# == operator in C++ Pointer of struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-keyword

I have the following structure in Visual Studio 2017:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* left, *right;
    int data;
};
```

Consider the following if-statement:

```
if ( root->left == root->right == NULL )
```

Why is the If-statement evaluated to true, 
even though pointer are not pointing to same location ?

Comment: `root->left == root->right` this is 0, `NULL` is also 0.

Comment: The intuitive mathematical notation of 3 items comparing equal doesn't translate directly to C++, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

Due to [operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the line

```
if ( root->left == root->right == NULL )
```

is same as

```
if ( (root->left == root->right) == NULL )
```

Depending on the values of `root->left` and `root->right`, the expression in the second pair of `()` could evaluate to `true` or `false`. What you end up with is either

```
if ( true == NULL )
```

or

```
if ( false == NULL )
```

The first them evaluates to `false` while the second one evaluates to `true`.

---

What you need to use is:

```
if ( root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running into problems with the way C++ will implicitly convert values.

Just as a background, NULL in C++ is defined to be 0. In a pointer context, this will implicitly convert into value to pointer-type value to test if it is null, but this definition of NULL as 0 is an integer in other contexts.

Now in your example, the result of `node->left == node->right` will give you a boolean value: `true` or `false`. Let's say they do not point to the same place in memory, so this comparison will return `false`. The `bool` value `false` can be implicitly converted into an integer with value 0 depending on the context.

In your if conditional, the compiler sees a 0 in the place of NULL. The result of the first comparison will return `false`. In the second comparison, you are comparing `false` (the result of the first comparison) against 0 (in place of NULL), so the compiler will assume you are trying to compare a `bool` to an integer. The compiler will then convert the `false` value into an integer of 0. Then the compiler will perform the second comparison. Hence, you end up testing 0 == 0, which is `true` of course. That is why the if statement evaluates to true under this scenario.

In brief, you cannot chain comparisons like this in C++. If you break it up into individual statements, you will get the behavior you expect.

Comment: that's why nullptr is to be preferred over NULL.